# Programa en c++ que ejecute Un comando

Tags: c++, programación-bajo-nivel, typings

Como creo un Programa en c++ que al ejecutarlo ejecute este comando:

ping https://www.paginaejemplo.com

Y se muestre el ping que manda esa pagina, gracias!

Comment: hola Jose. No está claro lo que preguntas porque deberias especificar cual es tu duda concreta, no cuál es la tarea. Has de investigar e intentarlo primero. MIra [ask] y [mcve] para más info. Un saludo

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

main ()
{

system ("ping www.google.com");
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Ya que me regañaron (es broma) en esto va el código
La librería "stdio.h" tiene la función system, que lo que hace es hacer unos procesos en el programa (por ejemplo system("cls") para limpiar la consola)

O en la consola de comandos como es este caso

Comment: gracias por el apoyo, pero en SO en español se pide quien postea una pregunta muestre el mínimo intento y aún con errores ayudarle

Comment: Lo tendré en cuenta, gracias por decirme

Comment: O también gracias a o sabia eso al respecto de que debo tener un mínimo de intento.